# Couldn't load initial seed urls using frontera in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, frontera

I'm trying to load seed urls for scrapy using frontera but seems not working, could any one help to load initial seed urls using frontera.

Comment: "seems not working" is astronomically unhelpful. What errors are you experiencing? What have you already tried? What command are you using to load the urls? Help us to help you.